# Show / Hide a div by a sliding effect

Tags: php, javascript, effects

This code switches visibility of a form:

```
function getStyle()
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("frm01").style.display;
    return temp;
}
function switch01()
{
    var current = getStyle();
    if( current == "none" )
    {
        document.getElementById("frm01").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("frm01").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

If the form becomes visible, the underlying div is pushing down on the page and vice versa.
How could I achieve that form becomes visible slowly, not in a second, but like a sliding effect.

Comment: Don't do it in barebones JS. Use jquery: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide. You'll save yourself a lot of anguish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in jQuery very easily.  This will work in all browsers.

```
$("#frm01").slideDown("slow", function() {
    // if you want to have some callback behavior, define that here
});

$("#frm01").slideUp("slow", function() {
    // if you want to have some callback behavior, define that here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A common technique is to hide it under another element, and then apply a transition effect.

CSS:

```
#frm01 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0 ); /* Default */
}

#frm01.animate {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0, 200px, 0 ); /* Move in Y-direction */
}
```

There are similair syntaxis for other browsers.